# How to exclude a cell from the sum total if another cell contains a specified value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm fairly new to excel and I'm drawing up a table for savings and budgets; one of my columns contains the prices of the things I want to buy.

The prices are then totaled up and then when a item is purchased I place an 'X' into a column, next to the purchased item If there is a better way, such as a tickbox, that fits better into a formula please let me know.

I want to know if there is a way for the formula to recognize an item has been purchased and subsequently remove the cost of said item from the sum.

A rough example of the output would be

- Item1=50, Item2=50.
- Total needed=100
- Item1=50, Paid=Yes
- Total needed=50

If there is a simpler method please let me know.
Thank you

Comment: Look I to `SumIfS`

Answer (score 1):

Dont exactly know how you have formatted your budget sheet.

You should checkout SumIF or SumIfs function to return the sum of cells that meet the supplied criteria.

> Criteria can be applied to dates, numbers, and text using logical
>   operators (>,<,<>,=) and wildcards (*,?) for partial matching.
>
> ```
> =SUMIFS (sum_range, range1, criteria1, [range2], [criteria2], ...)
> ```

So in your example, if we assume that

column A has the items

column B has the amounts

column C has the x for items which are purchased

```
=sumifs(B2:B100,A2:a100,"Item 1") // gives sum of only the Item 1 amounts

=sumifs(B2:B100,A2:a100,"Item 1",C2:C100,"x") // gives sum of only the Item 1 amounts which have been paid 

You can deduct these 2 to find the balance of unpaid amounts for each item
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately.  Excel did not see this as a formula